# How to fetch data from post method in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, post, tableview, alamofire

I have lists of data to be presented in tableview. The API works for POST method. But I don't get the data fetched on the tableview but it gets printed on the console. Can't we fetch data from POST method in Swift? Please help me to solve this problem.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class SpendingsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblHome: UITableView!
    var dictData:NSArray = NSArray()
    var appDictionary:NSDictionary!
    var appDictionary2:NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblHome.delegate = self
        tblHome.dataSource = self
        self.postData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dictData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath) as! SpendingsCell
        self.appDictionary = self.dictData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.spend_receipt?.text =    self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "receipt_number") as? String
        cell.store_amount?.text =    self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "amount") as? String
        cell.spend_storename?.text =    self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "store_name") as? String
        return cell
        //Data are not fetched here.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 156  //height for cell
    }

    func postData() {
        let headers = [
            "Authorization": "pZGFzbG9naW46QGRpZGFzJHRvcmU="   // its fake for privacy
        ]

        let todosEndpoint =  NSURL(string: "http://purchase_entries/Api/purchase_entry_list/")! as URL
        let USersIDs = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UsersId")

        let newTodo = ["user_id": USersIDs!]
        print(newTodo)
        Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newTodo, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response.result)

                if let JSON = response.result.value{
                    print("ion json",JSON)   // It prints the data
                    self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject)["rows"] as! NSArray

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `reloadData()` on your table view after you retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in your code:

```
 Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newTodo, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response.result)

```
if let JSON = response.result.value{
  print("ion json",JSON)   // It prints the data
  self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject)["rows"] as! NSArray
    if self.dictData.count > 0{
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           yourTableView.reloadData()
      }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you require :

```
   func callLoginWebService() {
        let token = SharedManager.getAuthenticationToken()
        let headers = [
            "token": token
        ]
        var params = [String:String]()
        params  = [
            "email":self.emailTxtField.text!,
            "password":self.passwordTxtField.text!]
        Alamofire.request(LoginUrl, method:.put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print("Request  \(String(describing: response.request))")
            print("RESPONSE \(String(describing: response.result.value))")
            print("RESPONSE \(response.result)")
            print("RESPONSE \(response)")

    }
    }
```

Save response.result.value to array or dictionary.Boom